# Drag and drop left behind an outline in Mac OS X 10.9.5

Tags: macos

I downloaded music last night, and as I dragged the file into my music folder, the outline from it froze on my screen.

I tried restarting my Mac, but the outline is still there. As well as this, I can no longer drag and drop items to folders.

The image shows up in front of any page that is opened. Any ideas?

Comment: seems like you were not doing a real reboot. maybe try `killall Finder` on the command line (Terminal.app)